# CSF Configuration Ignore NodeJS for Excessive Time

Tags: node.js, csf

I am getting a lot of these:

```
Excessive resource usage: *account* (9580 (Parent PID:9574))

Time:         Sat Oct 18 15:20:00 2014 -0400
Account:      *account*
Resource:     Process Time
Exceeded:     4832714 > 1800 (seconds)
Executable:   /usr/local/bin/node
Command Line: /usr/local/bin/node *Node JS File*
PID:          9580 (Parent PID:9574)
Killed:       No
```

I want to disable elapsed time for nodejs but keep the memory usage - I don't see any visible way to do this in `csf.pignore` **is this even possible to do?**

Right now I am just ignoring the individual files completely - that doesn't help in the event of a memory leak issue tho.